# Retrieve values from database to jradiobutton

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to implement a payroll system and I got some issues with the updating employees. I have stored the gender of the employees as a varchar in my DB. When I type in the employee id and click search button I want to get that info out of the database and display it in a male/female radio buttons according to the data. There are no errors in the code. but the problem is when I try to do that only male button appear selected which is by the way the default. Female radio button doesn't get selected even when the the data on the DB says Female. Can anybody please help me with this issue? below is my code.

```
package AppPackage;

import static AppPackage.AddEmployeeGUI.convertUtilDateToSqlDate;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class UpdateEmployeeGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;
ResultSet rs=null;

public UpdateEmployeeGUI() {
    initComponents();
    conn=MySQLConnect.ConnectDb();
}
private void SearchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeInfo WHERE EmployeeID =?";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,EmployeeIDSearchField.getText());

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()) { 
        String ID = rs.getString("EmployeeID");
        EmployeeIDField.setText(ID);
        String FN = rs.getString("FirstName");
        FirstNameField.setText(FN);
        String LN = rs.getString("LastName");
        LastNameF.setText(LN);
        String GN = rs.getString("Gender");
            if (GN =="Female"){
                MaleRadio.setSelected(false);
                FemaleRadio.setSelected(true);

            }
            else{
                FemaleRadio.setSelected(false);
                MaleRadio.setSelected(true);
            }      
        String CN = rs.getString("ContactNo");
        ContactNoField.setText(CN);
        String EM = rs.getString("Email");
        EmailField.setText(EM);
        SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dateValue = null;
        try {
            dateValue = date.parse(rs.getString("DateOfJoin"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
        jDateChooser.setDate(dateValue); 
        String Des = rs.getString("Designation");
        DesignationComboBox.addItem(Des); //getItemAt(int index); 
        String BS = rs.getString("BasicSalary");
        BasicSalaryField.setText(BS);

    }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}                                            

private void UpdateEmployeeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    // UPDATE EmployeeInfo SET FirstName='?', LastName='?', LastName='?', Gender='?', ContactNo='?',Email='?', DateOfJoin='?', Designation='?' WHERE EmployeeID='?';
    try{

        String sql1 = "UPDATE EmployeeInfo SET FirstName=?, LastName=?, Gender=?, ContactNo=?, Email=?, DateOfJoin=?, Designation=?, BasicSalary=? WHERE EmployeeID=?";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pst.setString(1,FirstNameField.getText());
        pst.setString(2,LastNameF.getText());
        pst.setString(3,GenderC);
        pst.setString(4,ContactNoField.getText());
        pst.setString(5,EmailField.getText());
        pst.setDate(6,convertUtilDateToSqlDate(jDateChooser.getDate()));
        pst.setString(7,DesignationComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.setString(8,BasicSalaryField.getText());
        pst.setString(9,EmployeeIDField.getText());

        pst.execute();

        String sql2 = "UPDATE employeebasicsalary SET BasicSalary=? WHERE EmployeeID=?";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
        pst.setString(1,BasicSalaryField.getText());
        pst.setString(2,EmployeeIDField.getText());
        pst.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully updated!");


    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
}                                                    

private void FemaleRadioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    GenderC = "Female";
}                                           

private void MaleRadioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    GenderC = "Male";
}                                         

private void ResetButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    EmployeeIDField.setText(null);
    FirstNameField.setText(null);
    LastNameF.setText(null);
    MaleRadio.setSelected(true);
    FemaleRadio.setSelected(false);
    ContactNoField.setText(null);
    EmailField.setText(null);
    jDateChooser.setCalendar(null);
    BasicSalaryField.setText(null);
    DesignationComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

Comment: post the sql query result

Comment: Try using `if (GN.equals("Female"))` instead of `==`

Comment: Yes, That solved my problem. Thank you very much Eric Hughes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the lines

```
if (GN =="Female"){
            MaleRadio.setSelected(false);
            FemaleRadio.setSelected(true);

        }
        else{
            FemaleRadio.setSelected(false);
            MaleRadio.setSelected(true);
        }
```

with

```
        if (GN.equals("Female")){
            MaleRadio.setSelected(false);
            FemaleRadio.setSelected(true);
        } else {
            FemaleRadio.setSelected(false);
            MaleRadio.setSelected(true);
        }
```

as `==` is used to compare the hash and values & `.equals` is used to check the values only..